# while exporting report in excel using php Not working on server but working on localhost?

Tags: php, sql, excel

I am trying to export report using php. it will work fine in localhost but while I am uploading in server it will not works fine and give output like below.(All the variable which i have used not not displaying here is declared  as global so there is not issue in variable declaring.)
[image: This is the image which i am getting while trying to export report]

```
$arrayissue = array();

            $count = 0;
            $screenshot_name = '';
            $productid = (string) filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'productid');


            $cycle = $_SESSION['Cycle'];
            $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
            $query2 = "SELECT Cycle_name FROM cycle_master WHERE Cycle_id='$cycle'";
            $result2 = $conn->query($query2);
            $row12 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);


            $ews = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
            $ews->setCellValue('a1', 'This is the Result For : ' . $row12[0]);
            $rowCount = 2;
            $title = 'a1:s1';
            $header = 'a2:s2';

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($title)->getFill()->setFillType(\PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('A9F5E1');

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($header)->getFill()->setFillType(\PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID)->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF00');

            $style = array(
                'font' => array('bold' => true,),
                'alignment' => array('horizontal' => \PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,),
            );

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($header)->applyFromArray($style);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle(
                    'A2:' .
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn() .
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()
            )->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
            $objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
            $styleArray = array(
                'font' => array(
                    'bold' => FALSE,
                    // 'color' => array('rgb' => 'FF0000'),
                    'size' => 10,
                    'name' => 'Calibri'
            ));
            for ($col = 'A'; $col != 'S'; $col++) {

                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setWidth(20);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($col)->applyFromArray($styleArray);
            }



            $queryforissue = "Select Issue_name from tmtool.project_issue_master where Project_id IN(Select Project_id from product_master Where Product_id='$productid')";
            $resultforissue = mysqli_query($conn, $queryforissue) or die(mysqli_error($conn));



            $countforissue = 0;
            $customeTitle = array();
            $customTitle1 = array('Execution ID', 'TC ID', 'Parent Site', 'Redirection Site');
            $customTitle2 = array('Total Error Observed Count', 'Issue(Pass/Fail)', 'Circle Name', 'Mobile Number', 'Date', 'Time', 'Product Name', 'Screen Shot Name', 'Comment', 'Actual Submitted Date');
            while ($rowissue = mysqli_fetch_array($resultforissue)) {
                array_push($arrayissue, $rowissue['Issue_name']);
                $countforissue++;
            }
            //print_r($arrayissue);

            $customTitle3 = array_merge($customTitle1, $arrayissue);
            $customTitle = array_merge($customTitle3, $customTitle2);
            print_r($customTitle);

            $alph = 'A';
            foreach ($customTitle as $value) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alph . $rowCount, $value);
                $alph++;
            }
            $rowCount++;

            $queryresult = "SELECT testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,'_', -1),UNSIGNED INTEGER) as num ,testcase_master.`Testcase_title`,testcase_master.`Subscriber_type`,defect_master.`Priority`,defect_master.`Category`,test_result_url.`Test_id`,test_result_url.`Assign_to`,test_result_url.`Child_site`,test_result_url.`Circle_name`,test_result_url.`Performed_date`,test_result_url.`Status`,test_result_url.`Comment`,test_result_url.`UrlProduct_name`,test_result_url.`Device_used`,test_result_url.`Simcard_no`,test_result_url.`Time` As Time_pass,defect_master.`Defect_id`,defect_master.`Defect_title`,defect_master.`Month`,defect_master.`Created_date`,defect_master.`Week`,defect_master.`Time`,defect_master.`Mobile`,defect_master.`Comment` as dcomment FROM tmtool.test_result_url LEFT JOIN tmtool.testcase_master  ON test_result_url.`Testcase_id`=testcase_master.`Testcase_id` LEFT JOIN tmtool.defect_master ON test_result_url.`Defect_id`=defect_master.`Defect_id` WHERE testcase_master.`Product_id` = '$productid' AND (test_result_url.`Performed_date` BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate') AND testcase_master.`Testcase_id` IN (SELECT Testcase_id FROM assigned_testsuite_testcase WHERE Testsuite_id IN (SELECT Testsuite_id FROM testsuite_master WHERE Cycle_id = '$cycle')) order by num";
            //$queryresult = "SELECT testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,testcase_master.`Testcase_title`,defect_master.`dcomment`,defect_master.`Defect_title`,defect_master.`Created_date`,defect_master.`Mobile`,defect_master.`Time`,test_result_url.`Test_id`, FROM tmtool.test_result_url LEFT JOIN tmtool.testcase_master ON test_result_url.`Testcase_id` = testcase_master.`Testcase_id` LEFT JOIN tmtool.defect_master ON test_result_url.`Defect_id` = defect_master.`Defect_id` WHERE testcase_master.`Product_id` = '$productid' AND testcase_master.`Testcase_id` IN (SELECT Testcase_id FROM assigned_testsuite_testcase WHERE Testsuite_id IN (SELECT Testsuite_id FROM testsuite_master WHERE Cycle_id = '$cycle'))";
            //$queryresult = "SELECT testcase_master.`Testcase_id`,testcase_master.`Testcase_title`,defect_master.`Comment`,defect_master.`Defect_title`,defect_master.`Created_date`,defect_master.`Mobile`,defect_master.`Time`,test_result_url.* FROM tmtool.test_result_url LEFT JOIN tmtool.testcase_master ON test_result_url.`Testcase_id` = testcase_master.`Testcase_id` LEFT JOIN tmtool.defect_master ON test_result_url.`Defect_id` = defect_master.`Defect_id` WHERE testcase_master.`Product_id` = '$productid' AND testcase_master.`Testcase_id` IN (SELECT Testcase_id FROM assigned_testsuite_testcase WHERE Testsuite_id IN (SELECT Testsuite_id FROM testsuite_master WHERE Cycle_id = '$cycle'))";
            $resultquery = mysqli_query($conn, $queryresult) or die(mysqli_error($conn));



            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultquery)) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $row['Test_id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $row['Testcase_id']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C' . $rowCount, $row['Testcase_title']);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D' . $rowCount, $row['Child_site']);


                for ($i = 0, $alpha2 = 'E'; $i < $countforissue; $i++, $alpha2++) {

                    $querygetResult = "Select $arrayissue[$i] from test_result_url where Test_id='$row[Test_id]'";
                    $getResult = mysqli_query($conn, $querygetResult) or die('Error querying database');
                    $rowResult = mysqli_fetch_array($getResult);
                    if($arrayissue[$i] == 'Landing_page_issue')
                    {
                        if($rowResult[0] == 'Fail')
                        {
                            $rowResult[0]='Yes';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $rowResult[0]='No';
                        }
                    }
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $rowResult[0]);
                    if ($rowResult[0] == 'Fail') {
                        $count++;
                    }
                }



                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $count);

                $alpha2++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Status']);
                $alpha2++;
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Circle_name']);
                $alpha2++;

                $elsealpha = $alpha2;
                $lastalpha = $alpha2;
                for ($j = 0; $j < 6; $j++) {
                    $lastalpha++;
                }


                if ($row['Status'] == 'Fail') {
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Mobile']);
                    $alpha2++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Created_date']);
                    $alpha2++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row['Time']);
                    $alpha2++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row["UrlProduct_name"]);
                    $alpha2++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row["Defect_title"]);
                    $alpha2++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($alpha2 . $rowCount, $row["dcomment"]);
                    $alpha2++;
                } else {
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($elsealpha . $rowCount, $row['Simcard_no']);
                    $elsealpha++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($elsealpha . $rowCount, $row['Performed_date']);
                    $elsealpha++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($elsealpha . $rowCount, $row['Time_pass']);
                    $elsealpha++;
                    $elsealpha++;
                    $elsealpha++;
                    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($elsealpha . $rowCount, $row['Comment']);
                }



                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($lastalpha . $rowCount, $row['Performed_date']);
                $alpha2 = '';
                $elsealpha = '';
                $count = 0;
                $rowCount++;
            }
            unset($count);
            unset($lastalpha);
            unset($elsealpha);
            unset($alpha2);

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Product Wise");
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-   officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="TestResults.xlsx"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            ob_end_clean();
            $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start off with printing some variables, that forces a header() and would destroy the excel file.

Remove the print_r($customTitle);

Comment: i will try it once i get the access of server. Is it affect on this? thanks @mortenSickel.If anything else is there than please let me know.